# make Get parameter not mandatory

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I have below code

```
@ns.route('/blah/<query>', methods=['GET'])
@api.doc(params={'query': 'Search ID'})
class myClass(Resource):
    @api.doc('blah', responses={ 200: 'OK' })
    def get(self, query):
        """Returns list of blah."""
```

which giving me below result:
[image]
[image]

question is: how can i make Get parameter value not mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *positive* that this is still the case and I'll be the first to admit that I'm new to this particular framework, but [based on the answers to this bug from 2013](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/114), it does not appear that the framework allows for this kind of behavior.

The recommended workaround is to create two `Resource`s, one with the parameter and one without.  That's the workaround I've used; usually pairing it with a simple base class with a method and an optional parameter that both call.

An example from the GitHub Issue:

```
class Users(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return users
    def post(self):
        #...

class User(Resource):
    def get(self, id=None):
        return find_user_by_id(id)
    def post(self):
        #...

api.add_resource(Users, '/users')
api.add_resource(User, '/users/<id>')
```